# Merging 2 shaders in Unity using CG programming and Shaderlab

Tags: unity-game-engine, merge, shader, cg, shaderlab

I want to merge the functionality of these two shaders for Unity. 
First shader is main shader that adds a glitch hologram effect. 
The Second shader is making a surface texture flimmer for added visual effect.

I am trying to merge my versions of the code, alternatively different passes that allows me to implement both features on same material, if possible.

I have tried shaderpass function, but cannot make it work.

Is it possible to do?

**1st shadercode**

```
    Shader "Custom/Cool Hologram Original"
{

    Properties
    {
    //This program takes an existing shader script and builds upon it, by adding the features :
    //Tintcolor - allowing for manipulation of colors
    //Transparency - Changing opaque in tags to transparency so that the model becomes transparent
    //Properties allow defining public manipulative variables

        _MainTex ("AlbedoTexture", 2D) = "white" {} //braces are useless leftover braces no longer needed according to Unity developer
        _TintColor("Tint Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)     //Public variable appearing in inspector
        _Transparency("Transparency", Range(0.0,0.5)) = 0.25
        _CutoutTresh("Cutout Threshold", Range(0.0,1.0)) = 0.2
        _Distance("Distance", Float) = 1
        _Amplitude("Amplitude", Float) = 1
        _Speed("Speed", Float) = 1
        _Amount("Amount", Range(0.0,1.0)) = 1
    }   
    //The actual shader program
    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }  //Added queue and transparent elements because order matters (see render order queu tag)
        LOD 100     //LOD means level of details and used for when player is close or far away

        ZWrite Off      //This is related to culling and depth testing, controlling if something is written to depth buffer. Zwrite off is for transparent objects      
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha             //See blend factors in unity doc. It is about render order and how they should blend

        Pass            //A pass can be made for each type of situation, like Virtual Reality etc

        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"        //Shaders does not use inheritance, it has got monobehaviour instead, so it must be defined as #included 

            struct appdata                  //Structs are objects with 2 objects each. appdata is passed in to v2f vert as argument
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;   //Variable with 4 floating point numbers x,y,z,w. POSITION is a semantic binding telling where it is to be used
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;      
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;    //SV_Position corresponds to screen position in Unity
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _TintColor;
            float _Transparency;
            float _CutoutThresh;
            float _Distance;
            float _Amplitude;
            float _Speed;
            float _Amount;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                v.vertex.x += sin(_Time.y * _Speed + v.vertex.y * _Amplitude) * _Distance * _Amount; //Allows sinusoidal movement to vertices in object space b4 translation to clip
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);      //See learnopengl.com to see 5 spaces: local space, world space, view space, clip space, screen space
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);           //Taking uv data from model and data from maintexture (see the shader texture in inspector)
                return o;                                       //Returns struct after it has been build in coordinate system, it will then be passed to fragment function
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target                      //Takes in v2f struct calling it i and then bind it to render target, which is frame buffer for screen
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) + _TintColor; //fixed 4 col is color. Can be fixed rgbA for 3 colors and an alpha channel. tex2D reads in colors from maintex and struct data from i
                col.a = _Transparency;                          //The colors are what actually drawed in this feature with tex3D
                clip(col.r - _CutoutThresh);                    //Not drawing pixels with certain amount of red color
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd shadercode**

```
    Shader "Custom/Offset 1"
{
    Properties {
    _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _ScrollSpeeds ("Scroll Speeds", vector) = (0, -3, 0, 0)
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }


        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            // Declare our new parameter here so it's visible to the CG shader
            float4 _ScrollSpeeds;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);

                 // Shift the uvs over time.
                o.uv += _ScrollSpeeds * _Time.x;

                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                // apply fog
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

> **3rd shadercode**

```
Shader "Custom/Combined" 
{

Properties 
{
_MainTex ("AlbedoTexture", 2D) = "white" {}
_HoloColor("Hologram Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
_Transparency("Transparency", Range(0.0,0.5)) = 0.25
_CutoutTresh("Cutout Threshold", Range(0.0,1.0)) = 0.2
_Distance("Distance", Float) = 1
_Amplitude("Amplitude", Float) = 1
_Speed("Speed", Float) = 1
_ScrollSpeeds("Scroll Speeds", vector) = (0,-3,0,0) //added from offset shader
_Amount("Amount", Range(0.0,1.0)) = 1

}

SubShader {

    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    LOD 100     
    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

    Pass 

    {

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata {

            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f {

            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1) //added from offset shader
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;

        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;
        float4 _HoloColor;
        float4 _ScrollSpeeds;
        float _Transparency;
        float _CutoutThresh;
        float _Distance;
        float _Amplitude;
        float _Speed;
        float _Amount;


        v2f vert (appdata v) 
        {
            v2f o;
            v.vertex.x += sin(_Time.y * _Speed + v.vertex.y * _Amplitude) * _Distance * _Amount;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);      
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);   
            o.uv += _ScrollSpeeds * _Time.x;    //Added from offset shader
            UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);     //added from offset shader

            return o;                                       
        }


        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target 
        {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) + _HoloColor; 
            col.a = _Transparency;                          
            clip(col.r - _CutoutThresh);    
            UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);   //Added from offset shader
            return col;

        }

        ENDCG
    }
}
```

Fallback "Diffuse"
}

Comment: Good news: both of these shaders use the same sorts of code to do what they do. All you have to do is figure out the math you want from the one and inject it into the other. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, we can fix problems, but we won't do the work for you. On top of that, shader code merging is more of an art than anything, I've found.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Draco, all I need is to know if it is doable. Normally I would pay for coding in commercial setting, but as this is for a shader course exam at college, I need to and want to manage and learn how to do it myself. I am however a bit stuck, so every hint and inspiration is helpful (for instance on where to start on the math needed, as it is often related to dot/cross-product calculations and matrices which is my achilles heel)

Comment: Is it doable with these shaders? Almost certainly. You just need to so a comparison of each block and find what's missing in one, present in the other. You'll hit a spot where you need to combine some mathy stuff (both shaders doing something different), and either it will be simple or you'll have to try a few things.

Comment: yes. I figure the structs is fairly easy, as they can probably hold the fog coords with no problem. So at the moment I am struggling with the vertex and fragment shaders. Specifically how to avoid overriding existing data in e.g. the output variable o and the fact that the shader must do two different things at the same time. Preferably, I will augment the 1st shadercode with an additional "blink" property and maybe have it allow for two textures both with opacity. Actually its a good challenge for my project.

Comment: You need the combined shader to do *both* things. E.g. take the one shader frag method, add the `UNITY_APPLY_FOG` line to it, and return the resulting *combined* result.

Comment: Hi Draco. I updated the 3rd code to my post. I think I solved the challenge now. At least I can set the horizontal flimmer while having the functionality from the other shader too. Perhaps there are better implementations, but for now I think its working. Would you care to take a look? Thanks a lot for your hints in the process, very much appreciated.

Comment: Yep, looks good to me. I haven't run any of them, so I can't say "that visually does everything correctly" but in terms of combining the code, it looks right. You're welcome.

Comment: I just discovered that the actual "glitch" effect with distorted vertices has disappeared. Suspecting some kind of arithmetic problem or overwriting of variables before returning output. Its related to the distance, amplitude and speed effect in properties (no longer have an effect)

Comment: The values it modifies are not ovewritten by the other shader's effects. It modifies the vertex, the other shader modifies the UVs. I don't see anything wrong with the function itself.